# visualization for zero inflated models

Tags: camera, visualization, zero, graph-visualization

I am currently working on my MSC thesis and I am working with a zero-inflated model due to the high amount of zeros in my data.
I am searching on the internet how I can visualize the summary of the model but don't understand/find how to do this.

I am working with cameratrap data, my response variable is number of antelope with some explanatory variables (area, vegetation, packing (with 3 levels: low, moderate, full; telling if there are a lot of different predators in the park present),predators, mesopredators.

Out of the summary I can for example see that the variable mesopredators has a positive influence on the number of antelopes. But is it also possible to show this in a figure?

Thanks in advance and have a nice day. :)